# My visualforce page disapears when I want go back to page in Salesforce Community

Tags: visualforce, community, experience-builder-page

I have the Visualforce Page (simple footer (link and text) ).
And I want to place it on Salesforce Community page.
It works fine when i open the page first time.
However when i go to another page in Community  and then go back to first page the footer(Visualforce page) is gone.

Any ideas ??

Any help will be appreciated .

Thank you.

Comment: Does the browser console say something?

Comment: @LuismaWhatakuai  no , there is nothing that could help.